# App shows blank page in Settings without a Settings.bundle file - ios8 only

Tags: ios, ios8

I have an iOS app that handles settings within the app. In iOS 7 it didn't appear in the Settings app (as intended), however running it on iOS 8 it now appears in Settings with an empty page.

I have tried tracing the Settings app in the iOS simulator, to see what it looks for before displaying the app icon, and it is checking for existence of the settings.bundle file, and also reads the info.plist file. So it could be something in the info.plist file.

The only capability the app uses is iCloud documents.

Comment: This was never resolved - and the Apple bug report was never closed. Due to the enhanced permissions that may be applied to most apps, nearly all apps now appear in Settings. I decided to put my app version information and acknowledgements there.